# ¿Como concatenar varios strings en una sola linea?

Tags: c++, string, vscode, dev-c++, concatenación

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string words = "";
    words += "Hi"+"this is a "+"new sentences"+"using C++";
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es concatenar en la variable `words` varias cadenas en una misma linea.
Estoy usando vscode como IDE, y el mismo me tira el siguiente error:
[image: error]

Y en consola al ejecutar obtengo el siguiente error:

```
cadena.cpp: In function 'int main()':
cadena.cpp:9:20: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [5]' and 'const char [13]' to binary 'operator+'
    9 |     words += "Hola"+" esta es una"+" nueva oracion"+" usando C++";
      |              ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |      |
      |              |      const char [13]
      |              const char [5]
```

Por lo cual mi salida esperada seria:

```
Hola esta es una nueva oracion usando C++
```

Estuve investigando y he visto que en C++ se concatena con `+` pero a mi no me funciono, por lo que si alguien me pudiera ayudar le estaría muy agradecido, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución mas sencilla en tu código sería quitarle los operadores de concatenación (los operadores +) y quedaría listo.

Así quedaría:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string words = "";
    words = "Hi " "this is a " "new sentences " "using C++";
    
    cout<<words;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aunque la respuesta propone una solución, no explica por qué se produce el error. También hay que tener en cuenta que [la concatenación de literales ocurre en tiempo de compilación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Concatenation).

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema es bastante sencillo: las *cadenas-primitivas* **no tienen ningún operador de concatenación**; este solo está definido para las clases `std::string`, no para las cadenas primitivas del lenguaje:

> "Hola" + " esta es una"

En esa línea estás intentando concatenar 2 cadenas *primitivas*, y eso no está permitido.

Podrías convertir todas las cadenas en `str::string`, tal como así:

```
words += string( "Hi" ) + string( "this is a " ) + string( "new sentences" ) + string( "using C++" );
```

Pero esa solución tiene implicaciones de rendimiento: cada llamada al constructor de `std::string` implica una reserva de memoria.

Personalmente, suelo hacerlo así:

```
words += "Hi";
words += "this is a ";
words += "new sentences";
words += "using C++";
```

Aunque similar, aquí solo se está creando y redimensionando una única `std::string` (la variable `words`), con lo que se minizan las operaciones de reserva de memoria y aumentamos un poco el rendimiento.

Comment: Otra opción es usar [el literal de string definido por la librería](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s): `words += "Hi"s + "this is a "s + "new sentences"s + "using C++"s;`

Comment: Cierto, no había caído. Aunque puede considerarse una *sintax sugar* para la 1ª parte de la respuesta, convertir todos los literales en `std::string`. Gracias por el aviso :-)